# How to reflect.New a slice and reflect.AppendSlice it to a source slice

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

I want to `reflect.New` an `[]interface{}` like `[]int` and append it into another slice.

My code must have an error, but I don't know how to make it right and how to understand deeply the `reflect.New` and `reflect.AppendSlice` usage.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var a []int
    var value reflect.Value = reflect.ValueOf(&a)


    if !value.CanSet() {
        fmt.Println("go here", value.CanSet())
        value = value.Elem() 
        fmt.Println("go here", value.CanSet())  
    }
    fmt.Println("go here", value.Type())    
    s := reflect.New(value.Type())
    fmt.Println("go here", s.Elem())
    value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, reflect.ValueOf(s.Elem()))
    value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, reflect.ValueOf([]int{1, 2}))                
    value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, reflect.ValueOf([]int{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9})) 

    fmt.Println(value.Kind(), value.Slice(0, value.Len()).Interface())
    //>>slice [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
}
```

But it gives an error:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.AppendSlice on struct Value

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x100a60, 0x1040e1a0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x720
reflect.flag.mustBe(0x99, 0x17)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:201 +0xe0
reflect.AppendSlice(0xfa7e0, 0x1040e130, 0x197, 0x1116a0, 0x1040e190, 0x99, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1825 +0x60
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox476529744/main.go:21 +0x800
```

[golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/gG4_CyKFKo)

Comment: Main idea is the []int cannot be converted to []interface{}. There is no implicit conversion, therefore you cannot append such slice neither without reflect nor with.

Comment: Thanks for your question, saving a lot time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The panic is on this line:

```
value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, reflect.ValueOf(s.Elem()))
```

The value `s.Elem()` is a `reflect.Value`. Use this value directly in the call to `AppendSlice`:

```
value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, s.Elem())
```

The expression `reflect.ValueOf(s.Elem())` returns the `reflect.Value` for a `reflect.Value`, not for the underlying `[]int`.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/HurU6ehiec)

Answer (score 1):

Try this working sample ( [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iwIFcnE0La) ):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{})).Elem()
    s = reflect.Append(s, reflect.ValueOf(1))
    s = reflect.AppendSlice(s, reflect.ValueOf([]interface{}{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}))
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

And see: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice :

> The question then, "Why can't I assign any slice to an []interface{},
>   when I can assign any type to an interface{}?"
>
> Why?
>
> There are two main reasons for this.
>
> The first is that a variable with type []interface{} is not an
>   interface! It is a slice whose element type happens to be interface{}.
>   But even given this, one might say that the meaning is clear.
>
> Well, is it? A variable with type []interface{} has a specific memory
>   layout, known at compile time.
>
> Each interface{} takes up two words (one word for the type of what is
>   contained, the other word for either the contained data or a pointer
>   to it). As a consequence, a slice with length N and with type
>   []interface{} is backed by a chunk of data that is N*2 words long.
>
> This is different than the chunk of data backing a slice with type
>   []MyType and the same length. Its chunk of data will be
>   N*sizeof(MyType) words long.
>
> The result is that you cannot quickly assign something of type
>   []MyType to something of type []interface{}; the data behind them just
>   look different.

Answer (score 0):

Error in line 21:

```
value = reflect.AppendSlice(value, reflect.ValueOf(s.Elem()))
```

See doc:

```
func AppendSlice(s, t Value) Value
The slices s and t must have the same element type.
```

When you dump values, you see:

```
Var dump s.Elem(): []int(nil) 
Var dump reflect.ValueOf(s.Elem()): {typ:0xfa840 ptr:0x1040e160 flag:407} 
Var dump value: []int(nil)
```

So you only need `s.Elem()` 
See: https://play.golang.org/p/KwXRxGyswg